# Getting attribute from xml

Tags: c#, xml

I have some xml like this:

```
<Action id="SignIn" description="nothing to say here" title=hello" />
```

Using LINQ to XML, how can I get the inner value of id? I am not on my dev machine (anothe machine with no dev stuff but so credentials) but I haven't tried:

```
 var x = from a in xe.Elements("Action")
     select a.Attribute("id").Value
```

Could I do something along those lines? I don't want a bool condition. Also, how would this be done using traditional XML methods before LINQ was introduced (I am on .NET 3.5 though).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse("<Action id=\"SignIn\" description=\"nothing to say here\" title=\"hello\" />");
var x = from a in doc.Elements("Action")
        select a.Attribute("id").Value;

string idValue = x.Single(); //Single() is called for this particular input assuming you IEnumerable has just one entry
```

With XmlDocument you could do

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("<Action id=\"SignIn\" description=\"nothing to say here\" title=\"hello\" />");
var x = doc.SelectSingleNode("Action/@id");
string idValue = x.Value;
```

HTH

Comment: Although I marked this as the answer, it doesn't work. My xml line is this: 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<opml version="1.0">
  <head>
    <title>Feed Subscriptions</title>
  </head>

    <outline title="Omea News" text="Omea News" description="Latest news about JetBrains Omea product family" xmlUrl="http://jetbrains.com/omearss.xml" htmlUrl="http://www.jetbrains.com/omea" type="rss" />

Perhaps I should use xpath?

Comment: The argument of SelectSingleNode _is_ an XPath query.
Can you explain more "it doesn't work"? What's the problem?
The xml fragment you copy is not valid: it is not properly closed and there are semicolons between attributes.
What do you want to extract from it?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a small example that shows how to do it:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        String xml = @"<Action 
                id=""SignIn"" 
                description=""nothing to say here"" 
                title=""hello""/>";

        String id = XElement.Parse(xml)
            .Attribute("id").Value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using "traditional" XML methods you would do something this:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("XML string here");

XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("Action");
string id = node.Attributes["id"].Value
```

Andrew has the right way to do this using Linq.

Answer (score 0):

Using a traditional XML Document, assuming you already had the action node you wanted, by using SelectSingleNode, or by traversing the document, you could get the value of the id attribute with.

```
ActionNode.Attributes("id").Value
```

Answer (score 0):

You pretty much have it, as long as 'xe' is the **XElement** that contains the one you are looking for *and* the "Action" element is the first/only "Action" element in the **XElement**:

`string x = xe.Element("Action").Attribute("id").Value;`